# Redis container error: requirepass wrong number of arguments

Tags: docker, redis

I have 8 Docker Desktop containers and all run fine except my Redis container. It says "Fatal config error (Redis 6.2.11) Reading the configuration file at line 2 'requirepass' wrong number of arguments".

I can't find the redis.conf file, but my docker-compose.yml has this line.

"command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}"

I'm setting up this repository for work. The README file had me point Docker to a env.txt file that had several other environment variables set, but it didn't have me set a REDIS_PASSWORD.

Despite that, I tried hard-coding a password with --requirepass "password" and resetting the container, but I got the same error.

I can't figure out if it's actually looking at that redis-server command in my yml file, or if there is a redis.conf somewhere with the variable that Docker is getting somewhere else.

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this? Is there a cache somewhere that's not clearing after I hardcoded a password, or am I looking in the wrong place? Or is this a flaw with the README file that failed to have me set a password with Redis?

I'm pretty new to Docker as well as Redis, so I'm struggling to setup my local environment.